# How do I change the sprite of a player in Unity?

Tags: unity, sprites

I am making a simple game in Unity, using C#. The game is about a blade that flies and collects coins. I want to make a shop where the player can change the image of the main character in the game.

I have variable that change the value according to the character the player chose; for example, if the player chose the yellow blade, the value of the variable would be 1. I don't know how to display different images for the blade object, according to this variable.

How do I change the sprite of a player in Unity?

Comment: The question as it is now is too vague: for example what is "picture"  - GameObject (sprite) or player's avatar on GUI? Asking clear questions with proper grammar *and* formatting will dramatically improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: sorry about the poor English.I start learning English only about year ago .I am from Israel.I mean ,how to change the Game OBject(sprite).

Comment: But to leave all the methods of the default sprite like thay was.Only the picture of the game object would change.

Answer (score 1):

If your player has a SpriteRenderer component then all you need to do is,

```
public Sprite newSprite;

GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = newSprite;
```

Then assign a Sprite (image) that you want to change to, you can also change the variable from script.